# Turn orderBy filter into a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a frequent pattern in my app and I am curious if it is possible to solve it through a custom directive:

```
select(ng-model='selectedEmployee' 
  ng-options="employee.name for employee in employees |
  orderBy:[employeeSort, 'name']")
```

`employees = [{name: EMP1, ...}, {name: EMP2, ...}]`

and my sort function is:

```
$scope.employeeSort = function(employee) 
{
    return employee._id != '0' ? '' : employee
}
```

As you can see I have a dummy element in my array that I always want to appear on the top, but sort the rest of items by some property (`name` in this particular case). I will always have the `_id = 0` for the dummy element.

So instead of writing a custom sort function for all the cases and setting my markup to use that function I would like to use a directive like this:

```
select(ng-model='selectedEmployee' keep_id_0_on_top
  ng-options="employee.name for employee in employees |
  orderBy:'name'")
```

Comment: Sure you can change into directive. Reusable code is what directives are all about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a filter would be more appropriate than a directive.
Something like

```
<select ng-options="item in items | orderBy:name | stickyTop:0">
```

and

```
filter('stickyTop', function(array, id) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
        if (array[i].id === id) {
           var topEls = array.splice(i, 1);
           array.unshift(topEls[0]);
           break;
        }
    }
    return array;
})
```

(code non tested, but you get the idea)